# Defective Matrix and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A matrix $A$ is called defective if $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity $m > 1$ for which the associated eigenspace has a basis of fewer than $m$ vectors; that is, the dimension of the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$ is less than $m$. Use the eigenvalues of the following matrices to determine which matrices are defective.

Example:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 7 & 2 \\ -2 & 0 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$.

I found the eigenvalues= 7,7,5 where 7 has a multiplicity of 2.

My Problem is: How to decide a matrix is defective? Am I supposed to consider only the value 7 or both 7 and 5 because the definition says it is defective if eigenspace associated with the value is less than $m$.

Comment: Check that the eigenspace corresponding to $7$ has dimension $2$.

Comment: I got 2 vectors if I am considering 7. They are [-1 0 1] and [ 0 1 0].

Comment: So, it is not defective?

Comment: The eigenspace of the eigenvalue $5$ (which has multiplicity $1$) has dimension $1$ and the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $7$ (which has multiplicity $2$) has dimension $2$. Hence it is not defective.

Comment: So it means that we just have to check for the vales which have multiplicity greater than 1?

Comment: Yes, if an eigenvalue has multiplicity one, then you know that the eigenspace has dimension one.